# AWS Simple Workflow Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-swf

The policy on the SWF documentation doesn't seem to work. Has anyone else got the following to work?

```
{
"Version":"2008-10-17",
"Statement":[{
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":["swf:*"
        ],
        "Resource":["*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there's a known issue with AWS SWF not respecting IAM group policies. A user policy should work though: http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Amazon-SWF/2122535754209136